# Cannot build my app in Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 after an upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on app and everything was going as planned, then i **upgraded flutter** to the latest version.

i tried **flutter doctor -v** everything looks **good**.

this is the error message i get when i try to build my app:

```
Compiler message:
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-1.1.3/lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart:42:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
                       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Flutter has added the `DecoderCallback` in [this commit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/3bbf54d79fceab8e20d4e43954ed00f52a3591fb), which is now a required argument for the `load` function. Looking at the `cached_network_image` dependency you are using, this issue is already stated in their README.md:

> If you are experiencing one of the following errors upgrade to 2.0.0-rc.

So, you can solve this issue by upgrading `cached_network_image` in your `pubspec.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with cached_network_image. Check out the documentation. I believe you need to go to this version - 
cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc